# How to load mask in Flash with AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, mask

I am trying to create a Flash animation with AS2 and I need an effect which will 'fill up' or load an image like in a preloader. I have followed the tutorial [here](http://flashexplained.com/preloaders/creating-a-preloader-for-your-flash-site-using-the-image-of-a-bottle-and-a-rectangular-mask/) which works great for preloaders but I need the animation to play during the actual content. From that tutorial, the code i am currently using is:

```
mcJewelHalfRect._height = 1;
this.onEnterFrame = function():Void {
var loadedData:Number = this.getBytesLoaded();
var allData:Number = this.getBytesTotal();
var percent:Number = Math.round(loadedData/allData*100);
mcJewelHalfRect._yscale = percent;
if (loadedData >= allData) {
gotoAndStop(10);
delete this.onEnterFrame;
}
};
```

This should load the rectangle mask over the image I want expanded, but as it's intended for a prefoader it won't work properly. So is there a way to change it so that it's not based on loaded data but just fills automatically over a set time?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: The effect that I want is basically [like this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57098966/SINF_300x250_MPU.swf) with things scrolling in and 'filling up' (not sure how else to describe it!) Would that be best to do in code or with timeline animations?

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of this:

```
this.onEnterFrame = function():Void {
var loadedData:Number = this.getBytesLoaded();
var allData:Number = this.getBytesTotal();
var percent:Number = Math.round(loadedData/allData*100);
mcJewelHalfRect._yscale = percent;
```

Using this

```
var framesPassed = 0;
this.onEnterFrame = function():Void {
var percent:Number = Math.round(framesPassed / 100);
mcJewelHalfRect._yscale = percent;
```